# selecting class name as variable for more than 2 words in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to select a div that contains more than 2 words as a class name in a variable.
i.e, `$("div[class='LIKES & DISLIKES']")` this works fine but the problem is i have this class name `LIKES & DISLIKES` in a variable, I cant use variable in `$("div[class='+ variable +']")`.
I tried something

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName(variable)
```

but this gives me HTML collection which i dont know how to retrieve my div elements from that.

So I  defined a text in the class name so I can hide all by using
`$("[class*='showtab']").hide()` and show that that class for which anchor tag has been clicked `$(".showtab"+lab).show()`
this works fine till two-word class name i.e. `Style cat` but it's not working for more than 3 words class name i.e. `LIKES & DISLIKES`

This works fine for `$('.showtabStyle.cat')` but not for `$('.showtabLIKES.&.DISLIKES')` but I am having LIKES.&.DISLIKES in a variable which I append it to the text `showtab`

My code do something like this

```
 $(document).on("click", ".nav-link-in", function (e){
     var labtemp = $(this).text().trim().replace(/\s+/g, ".");
     var lab = labtemp.replace(/\([\s\d\/]+\)/, ""); // this to remove extra space for `LIKES & DISLIKES` and replace it with .this gives `LIKES.&.DISLIKES` as i am removing number within bracket also
     $("[class*='showtab']").hide();
     $(".showtab"+lab).show();
  }
```

this code works fine for one/two word class name but not for more than two.

`$("div[class='showtabLIKES & DISLIKES']")` works great but as i said i have class name `LIKES & DISLIKES` in a variable.

Comment: It’s `$("div[class='" + variable + "']")`, not `$("div[class='+ variable +']")`. For [`HTMLCollection`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), read the docs.

Comment: It doesn't work either

Comment: What exactly doesn’t work? If `$("div[class='showtabLIKES & DISLIKES']")` works as expected and `variable == "LIKES & DISLIKES"` holds, then `$("div[class='showtabLIKES & DISLIKES']")` is equivalent to `$("div[class='showtab" + variable + "']")`.

Comment: Thanx it worked, my IDE was creating issue when I was writing that syntax, I made some mistake

Comment: This is the worst possible value for a class... Now you have a class `showtabLIKES`, `&`, and `DISLIKES`. You don't seem to understand what is going on. Get back to your HTML basics.

Answer (score 1):

A single class name cannot contain more than one word, separated by spaces. That's just not allowed. So if you are saying you have one class "likes & dislikes", that's not valid. Those are probably three classes (if `&` is a valid classname, not sure). If you mean that you have two variables for two classes, and you want to select elements that have both of these classes then you should do:

```
$("."+var1+"."+var2)
```

With [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) you can even do:

```
$(`.${var1}.${var2}`)
```

Comment: Hey Bram, then how it works for Style cat as class name but not for likes & dislikes

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say, but one class name **cannot** contain spaces. When you have a space, that means that there are two classes. I.e. `<div class="one two"/>` does not contain one class `one two` but two classes, namely class `one` and a class `two`.

Comment: then i can select that div using those two /three class using . operator, like $('.one.two') or $('.one.two.three')

Comment: But note that `.` is not an operator. It is a class selector, it selects an element by its class.

Comment: So it should work for likes & dislikes, I just followed basics but I am stuck in this part , $('.showtab' +lab) and lab ='likes.&.dislikes'

Comment: I see it doesn't accept two . Selector that's why it's creating an issue I think

Comment: You don't seem to understand the basics of HTML classes. Please get a decent hold of HTML before you start using JS. Post a JSFiddle showing what is not working.